# Cannot return the right if statement

Tags: c++, char, return, constants

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main(){

    const char* a = 0;
    const char* b = "Georgi";
    printf("Hello, write your name!\n");
    scanf_s("%s", &a);
    if (a = b){
        printf("\nHi,",b ,", its nice to see you my friend.");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nHello, its nice to meet you. My name is Supa-Dupa Computer!");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

So i'm trying to make program that returning sense after inserted specific name.
First time it worked, but when i input "Georgi" it printed me the "else" sense. Now when i input even only a sign, the program just exit. Any suggestions where i go wrong ?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour (`a` is uninitialized when you read into it) and you're comparing pointers (use `strcmp` instead.)

Comment: assignment vs. comparison round 810.

Comment: Is this supposed to be C or C++? In either language, you need `==` not `=` for comparision; but even if you fix that, you can't use that to compare nasty C-style strings. Either use the C++ library `std::string`, or the C library `strcmp` (In C, you also need to provide an array for `a` to point to, and somehow avoid overflowing if the input it too long.)

Comment: I would be very surprised if MSVC did not warn on `if (a = b)`. In the event that you use `scanf_s` in the future, beyond making sure that what you give it can actually be written to (a string literal cannot), take care to actually pass in the right type. `%s` expects a `char *`, not a `const char **`. You are also not passing in the buffer size, and the documentation for that function states that it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `a = b` doesn't compare `a` to `b`, it assigns. You want `==`.

Secondly, `==` is still incorrect, as you are comparing `char*`s, which are just pointers. You want `strcmp(a,b)`.

And finally, `a` is not initialized when you `scanf_s` into it. Allocate the memory first, or just use `std::string`.

Mind you, if this actually is C++ as in your tag, you should be using `cin` and `cout` instead of `printf` and `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

`a = b` means "assign b's value to a" what you want is `a == b` which means "check if a and b have the same value", but for comparing strings in C you should use `strcmp` as pointed out by juanchopanza, also a  is not initialized, you need to allocate memory for it either by usign `malloc` or by changing it into an array.